# RxSwift: Extra argument 'onError' in call

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift, option-type

I have following code in Swift 4 with RxSwift

```
worthReacting.flatMap{ (userSearch) in
        translator.getTranslation(ofWord: userSearch)
        }.subscribe(
            onSuccess: {(dataModel) in
                state.value = .translation(word: dataModel.definition,
                                           translations: dataModel.translations)
        },
            onError: {(error) in
                state.value = .networkError
        },
            onCompleted: {
                state.value = .unknownWord
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

`worthReacting` has type of `Observable<String>`
`translator.getTranslation` returns `Maybe<DataModel>`

I'm getting build error

> Extra argument 'onError' in call

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Maybe` flatmaped into `Observable` produces `Observable`. `Observable` can not emit `onSuccess` event, instead it will emit `onNext`. Following code will work:

```
worthReacting.flatMap{ (userSearch) in
        translator.getTranslation(ofWord: userSearch)
        }.subscribe(
            onNext: {(dataModel) in
                self.state.value = .translation(word: dataModel.definition,
                                           translations: dataModel.translations)
        },
            onError: {(error) in
                self.state.value = .networkError
        },
            onCompleted: {
                self.state.value = .unknownWord
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who get the OP's error, but have a different cause, check that you have not incidentally make one of your closures `throwing` by not making your `do-catch` clause exhaustive.

Also, take care that you don't use a single-statement closure (in this case you should explicitly `return`).